# How to populate a html table with the result of a a request ajax

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I have the next html table that i want to populate with the result of an ajax request:
table t_extension

```html
 <table id="t_extension" class="table table-striped">
     <thead>
             <tr>
                 <th>Extension</th>
                 <th>Name</th>
                 <th>Action</th>
             </tr>
     </thead>
   </table>
```

and i call the api via ajax

```js
$.ajax(
    {   
        type: "GET",
        url: 'https://164.132.84.147:55331/123456/pbx/extension/listall',
        data: "{}",
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        dataType: 'json',
        cache: false,
        success: function(data)
        {   
            console.log(data);

        }
    });
```

The api call via ajax give as result an array[8] that contains some objects with the attributs extension and name

I would like to populate the t_extension table with the result of the ajax request that call the api.
And i wrote the next code to populate the table helping by the differnts forums that talk about this point.

```js
$.ajax(
    {   
        type: "GET",
        url: 'https://164.132.84.147:55331/123456/pbx/extension/listall',
        data: "{}",
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        dataType: 'json',
        cache: false,
        success: function(data)
        {               
            $('#t_extension').append(
                $.map(data.Extension, function (extension, index) {
                return '<tr><td>' + extension + '</td><td>' + data.Name[index] + '</td></tr>';
            }).join());
        } ,

        error: function (msg)
        {            
                    alert(msg.responseText);
                }
    });
```

but it's not working, the table is not populated.

Comment: Please show your sample JSON response.

Answer (score 0):

You have to append `<tbody>` into the `table` first and then append your `<tr>...</tr>` staff from ajax request into `<tbody>`

Your HTML:

```
 <table id="t_extension" class="table table-striped">
     <thead>
             <tr>
                 <th>Extension</th>
                 <th>Name</th>
                 <th>Action</th>
             </tr>
     </thead>
     <tbody></tbody>
   </table>
```

Your `append`:

```
$('#t_extension > tbody').append(...);
```

Comment: Could you please write the code how to append the <tbody> into the table because i 'm not sure i understand your response.